# Sending parameters to local HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, xml, local-files

I'm fetching an URL address from XML file. That URL links to an HTML file,
the html builds itself (using javascript) according to a parameter that I'm sending to him.
One example line from the XML is:

```
<Module Id="1" URL="../../Modules/MessageComposer/module.htm" SRC="email.png" />
```

I would like to set this line to:

```
<Module Id="1" URL="../../Modules/MessageComposer/module.htm?UID=1" SRC="email.png" />
```

And I want to aks if this will work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect your HTML file will do with the provided parameter ?

Comment: it's a parameter to a SQL query, so I just want to know if it's possible to make it work like this

Comment: A local file won't query anything unless you use a local server to fetch your URLs...

Comment: do u want to query for a WebSql db ?

Comment: no, for Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: @user1176926 — How are you expecting the database to be accessed?

Comment: I have allready access to the database that is working fine, the only thing I need to fix, is get a parameter from the address bar into the HTML file that I built, then it is no problem to pass it to the database.

Comment: I have heard of a way to use the '#' symbol in order to send attributes to HTML, how to send it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A local file won't query anything unless you use a local server to fetch your URLs.

So if you want a local file to react on parameters passed to it's URL, for example in HTML you can parse `window.location.search` with JavaScript and do something with it.

If you want to locally trigger a query, use a simple local server as LAMP/WAMP.

---

Get your parameters:

```
var params = window.location.search.slice(1).split("&");
```

With each get name and value:

```
for(var p=0; p<params.length; p++) {
  var nv = params[p].split("=");
  var name = nv[0], value = nv[1];
  // What you want to do with name and value...
}
```

---

Generating an HTML anchor with XSL:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Module">
  <xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="URL"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="URL"/>
  </xsl:element name="a">
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I see, can you please give me an example how to do it?

Comment: With javascript or with a local server?

Comment: I'm getting the parameter within javascript, so how should I write the link in the first place, and how to fetch it with the parameter I want?

Comment: OK, I know how to fetch a parameter from javascript if the HTML page does getting parameters, my question, is how to build the link in the XML file, and how to make sure that the HTML file that I built will receive that parameter?

Comment: Do you use XSL to generate your HTML page ?

Comment: no, I don't use XSL to generate the HTML, I want to write the link in the XML file so it will point directly to the HTML file that I built.

Comment: So how do you build your HTML file, is it hand written? And you XML file, is it generated or hand written ?

Comment: OK, how do I do it? the parameter I want to transfer to my HTML file called "UID", and how to I create the link to the HTML file

Comment: I have heard of a way to use the '#' symbol in order to send attributes to HTML, how to send it?

Comment: The '#' symbol is not use to send attributes but to join an anchored section in the HTM page.

Comment: Is it possible for you to help me solving this talking in our emails or something like that?

Comment: Meet me [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8015/chat-between-sinsedrix-and-user1176926)

Comment: I'll be more then happy if you could talk to me in my email: taltcher@gmail.com